# Adquiring a SOAP trace for debugging is not woking

Tags: soap, system.diagnostics, tracelistener, docusignapi

I am using Docusign API to create and retrieve "envelopes" for signing. (docusign.com for more info).

Basically i am having some issues trying to adquire a SOAP trace based on their instructions https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK/wiki/How-to-acquire-a-SOAP-trace-for-debugging-%28Windows%29

And here is where i am needing some help. Has anyone, using these intructions from Docusing support (that comes from the Microsoft page and according to one Community Comments, seems not to work) been able to create a trace?

i have tried all possible combinations and i don't see no log file created so far.

I really appreciate any help you can provide me with.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here's the trace config I use in my App.config for DocuSign.  You'll need to clean up the log a bit (look for "<<<" and ">>>" before/after each call.

First add this to the `system.serviceModel` section:

```
  <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging
        logEntireMessage="true"
        logMalformedMessages="true"
        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
        maxMessagesToLog="50"
        maxSizeOfMessageToLog="500000000" />
    </diagnostics>
```

Then add this to the `configuration` section:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" tracemode="protocolonly" maxdatasize="52428800" >
        <listeners>
          <add name="MyTraceFile"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>

    <sharedListeners>
      <!-- Set path here. Make sure the app has permission to write to the location.-->
      <add
        name="MyTraceFile"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="c:\temp\DsTrace.log" />
    </sharedListeners>

    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>

  </system.diagnostics>
```

One more note, the DocuSign staff will really appreciate it if you remove the `PDFBytes` elements from your trace before you send it, unless that's needed for what you're having them troubleshoot.